# Textbox not showing when using tooltip-master alongside with bootstrap v3.3.5 and jquery 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-tooltip

I have the following code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvvEa .

I'm using: `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`, `tooltipser-master` (https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster), and `Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.5`.

I have just one HTML textbox with a default BS button (for learning purposes). My problem is that the textbox is not displayed. I read that might be a problem with some conflicts between jquery codes. Any tip top solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Your codepen work isn't right. Please change your <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.tooltipster.js"></script> line.

Comment: @ebilgin Have a check now please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for **hidden textbox** but I recommend have a little research on **tooltipster**. Please add this css to your css block.

```
.tooltip.tooltipstered {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```